# Print this HashCode from ArrayList in Java

Tags: java

Going through the list of existing users is determined whether there is a same  ID in the list of users who are added. If there is, this user will be deleted from the list of existing ones.

Question is: if I do this I got `HashCode` printed, if I put just `(i)` l got index printed. How to `Array.toString(i)` this? There is always errors.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
        for (int u = 0; u < usersToAdd.size(); u++) {
            if (((User) users.get(i)).Id == ((User) usersToAdd.get(u)).Id)
                users.remove(u);
        }
    }

    users.addAll(usersToAdd);

    for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) { 

        System.out.println(users.get(i)); // how to print them ?
    }
```

Comment: User in parenthesis is second Class btw

Comment: Post your `User` class. You should add the `toString()` method there ...

Comment: Your class `User` must override the `toString()` method to print something else than `User@<hashcode>`, which is what the default `hashCode` in class `Object` does.

Comment: public class User {
 public int Id;
 public String ime;

 public User(int id, String ime) {
  this.Id = id;
  this.ime = ime;
 }
}

Comment: Yeah, you have to implement the method `public String toString() { return id + ": " + name; }` (for example).

Answer (score 1):

You should normally override `toString()` method of the `User` class and then print users like this:

```
class User {
    private String name;

    public String toString() {
        return "User: " + name;
    }
}

List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
...
for (User user : users) {
    System.out.println(user);
}
```

If you really have to have collection of Objects (I would not recommend this):

```
for (Object user : users) {
    System.out.println(user);
}
```

UPD: without toString() method you can just:

```
for (User user : users) {
    System.out.println("User: " + user.getName() + user.getId());
}
```

Comment: l did but there is an error on users in parenthesis now?
on start there is 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to User

Comment: @Cleverson: It seems your collection elements is of type Object (e.g. List or List<Object>), while it should be User (List<User>)

Comment: I'd advice only overriding toString() for debug purposes and use a method which outputs a more meaningful message for other purposes such as feedback to the user or logging.

Comment: ty, l tried to print them throw for in main metod, is that possible without toString() metod in User class?

Comment: @Cleverson: I updated my answer to show how to do it without toString method

Comment: @nogard that is if l put get methods in class User l suppose?

Comment: @Cleverson: well, I don't know API of your User class, but instead of getId() I see you just call user.Id

Answer (score 0):

You should override the `toString()` method:

```
public class User { 

    public int Id; 
    public String ime; 

    public User(int id, String ime) { 
        this.Id = id; 
        this.ime = ime; 
    } 

    public String toString() {
        return "Id: " + Id + ", ime: " + ime;
    }

}
```

and use `id` instead of `Id`.

Comment: ty, l tried to print them throw for in main metod, is that possible without toString() metod in User class??

Comment: You can print `user.Id` and `user.ime` instead of user ... or you can use some getters ...

Answer (score 0):

`User` class should override `toString` method, since the default implementation of it is the hash code:

```
public class User { 
    public int Id; 
    public String ime; 

    public User(int id, String ime) { 
        this.Id = id; this.ime = ime; 
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Id: " + Id + ", Ime: " + ime;
    }

}
```